# Visual Studio 2010 How to replace large string variable with new XML while debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and have a breakpoint set to stop execution of the app after a variable is set with contents of a large XML string.  I want to replace the contents of the string with a different XML string.  I open the Text Visualizer but it does not allow me to modify the string.  How can I change the contents of the variable?  I have the variable displayed in a Watch Window but only the first line of the string is copied.

Comment: Have you tried using the Immediate WIndow ant typing var = 'my xml';?

Comment: The string contains double quotes.  I am looking for somethink like the Text Visualizer but be able to edit the contents.

Comment: why dont you create a constant with the new xml, leave that constant alone and on the breakpoint use the immediate window to change the value to the constant value

Comment: You can escape double-quotes.  Just paste the string into notepad and do a Replace All.  For c#, replace " with \" or for VB replace it with "".  It'll work, I promise.

Answer (score 3):

My workaround for this:

- Copy the text from Text Visualizer to notepad:

  ```
  <table xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com/furniture">
    <name>African Coffee Table</name>
    <width>80</width>
    <length>120</length>
  </table>
  ```
- Edit the value according your needs:

  ```
  <table xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com/furniture">
    <name>African Coffee Table</name>
    <width>100</width>
    <length>200</length>
    <weight m="kilo">12</weight>
  </table>
  ```
- Replace all `"` with `""`:

  ```
  <table xmlns=""http://www.w3schools.com/furniture"">
    <name>African Coffee Table</name>
    <width>100</width>
    <length>200</length>
    <weight m=""kilo"">12</weight>
  </table>
  ```
- Open Immediate Window
- Assign the new value to the variable using verbatim string literal `@""`, e.g.

  ```
  myXml=@"<table xmlns=""http://www.w3schools.com/furniture"">    <name>African Coffee Table</name>    <width>100</width>    <length>200</length>    <weight m=""kilo"">12</weight>  </table>"
  ```